# Changing all links with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to take things from another site and add href's a link. But my JQuery code just took the first href and change every hrefs' with that.

The code takes a table  and  tag. I just want to add a link in front of href.
I mean first href is like "example/example1" and I want to change it like "https:example.com/example/example1".

PHP cUrl code:

```
<?php 

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.planetdp.org/subtitlelist?translator=Kill+Master");

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
$sonuc = curl_exec($curl);


preg_match_all('@<td class="subtitle1">(.*?)</td>@si',$sonuc,$info);
$info = $info[0];
echo '<ul class="movie-name">';
for($i=0; $i < count($info);$i++){
    echo '<li class="content">';
    echo $info[$i];
    echo '</li>';

}
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

And JQuery code:

```
$(".alert-link").attr("href");
var href = $(".alert-link").attr("href");
$(".alert-link").attr("href", "https://planetdp.org"+href);
```

Comment: You need to loop over the elements, and change then independently, as the `href` variable will only contain a single value.

Comment: Use DOM: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through all the `classes` you want to change `href` on

```
$('.alert-link').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr("href", "https://planetdp.org"+href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested working good. Hope this help you.

```
$('a').each(function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr("href", "https://planetdp.org"+href);
});
```